# MongoDB - $nin invalid operator with aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I have a function that should return a count of users created in a given period and group by invited and non invited. On the `$cond` operator, I need to compare if the field `tkbSponsor` is not `null` and is not equals `example@example.com`. If this condition results to true, then the user was invited. Otherwise, he wasn't invited.

```
var countByPeriod = function(req,res) {
    var initialDate = req.body.initialDate;
    var finalDate = req.body.finalDate;

    User.aggregate([
        {
            "$match": {
                "timeStamp": {
                    "$gte": new Date(initialDate),
                    "$lt": new Date(finalDate)
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": null,
                "total": { "$sum": 1 },
                "invited": {
                    "$sum": {
                        "$cond": [
                            { 
                                "tkbSponsor": {
                                    "$nin": ["example@example.com",null] 
                                }
                            },
                            1,
                            0
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ], (err,result) => {
        if (!err)  {
            if (result.length) res.send(result[0]);
            else res.send({"total": 0,"invited":0});
        } else {
            res.sendStatus(500);
            console.log(err);
        }

    });

};
```

By the way, this function is giving me an error when executed:

```
{ [MongoError: invalid operator '$nin']
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'invalid operator \'$nin\'',
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'invalid operator \'$nin\'',
  code: 15999 }
```

Just an observation. I used to use the `$cond` operator as below, because I didn't needed to compare with `null`:

```
"$cond": [
           { 
             "$ne": ["$tkbSponsor", "example@example.com"]
           },
           1,
           0
]
```

And it works. However, now I have also to compare if the `tkbSponsor` is not null and using `$nin`, is giving me that error.

Answer (score 0):

Change that to use **[`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/and/#exp._S_and)** together with the **[`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/)** coalesce as :

```
{
    "$cond": [
        { 
            "$and": [
                { "$ne": ["$tkbSponsor", "example@example.com"] },
                { 
                    "$ne": [
                        { "$ifNull": [ "$tkbSponsor", null ] },
                        null
                    ] 
                }
            ]
        }, 1, 0
    ]
}
```

or using [**`$or`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/or/#exp._S_or) as

```
{
    "$cond": [
        { 
            "$or": [
                { "$eq": ["$tkbSponsor", "example@example.com"] },
                { 
                    "$eq": [
                        { "$ifNull": [ "$tkbSponsor", null ] },
                        null
                    ] 
                }
            ]
        }, 0, 1
    ]
}
```

The **[`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/)** operator's presence is to act as an **`$exists`** operator by replacing "non-existant" or null fields with a `null` value for evaluation.

Running this should return the correct results as the earlier **[revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41512641/2)** was only evaluating documents where the `tkbSponsor` field `exists` AND has either a value of `null` or  "example@example.com".

With **[`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/)**, "non-existant" fields are also evaluated as the operator gives them the null value.

Comment: Is compare with ```null```equals to using ```$exists``` operator? The query is working now, but the result is not correct. I guess that the comparison with ```null``` is always resulting true.

Comment: Could you edit your question to give some sample documents for testing and also show what you expect the correct result to be from that sample?